# Derived Queries not working with DBRef

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-document

I am using Mongo with Spring Data.

I have two (first class) entities (@Documents) Entity1 and Entity2, where Entity1 has a reference (@DBRef) of Entity2 within it. Everything works fine, but when executing derived queries such as :

```
public List<Entity1> findByEntity2Property1(String property1)
```

The above query returns no results although there are documents with the given query params. Why is that?

Comment: Hi, could you find any solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the query can work as you expect it to work as MongoDB pretty much does not allow restricting results on properties of related documents pointed to via a `DBRef`. So you essentially have to query all `Entity2` instances matching the given value on property `Property1` and then query for `Entity1` instances matching the `DBRef`ed property against the results of the first query.

Comment: thanks! is that the only (and the recommended) way out here? Or are there (possibly, better) alternates?

Comment: Also, `then query for Entity1 instances matching the DBRefed property against the results of the first query` - how do you do this?

Comment: @Saket Have you found a solution?