# Querying on a @DBRef field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

Using: Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, Spring Data MongoDB 1.0.0.RELEASE

I have a document class defined like this:

```
@Document
public class MyDoc
{
  @Indexed
  @DBRef
  private User owner;
  ...
```

I'm trying to select all MyDoc instances for a particular user with this repository definition:

```
public interface MyDocRepository extends CrudRepository<MyDoc, String>
{
  List<MyDoc> findByOwner(User owner);
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't find anything: the code runs fine, no exception, but alas nothing  is found.

So what is the proper way to select documents by a DBRef-ed field?

**NB**. I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138350/derived-queries-not-working-with-dbref) but my use case is simpler as I don't want to filter by a property of the DBRef-ed entity.

**Update**: Until repositories support finding by DBRef, I've decided to go with a simple workaround: use the MongoTemplate to form a query that uses a *com.mongodb.DBRef* as a field criteria. Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this not supported by Spring Data [yet](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-347):

I think the problem resolves around the fact that a proxy is used, but I haven't looked at the code yet.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the relevant JIRA, I've upvoted it and am watching it.

Comment: This is fixed in 1.1.0.M1 (changelog: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.1.0.M1/changelog.txt)

Comment: This is really fixed and you original query should work now.